# How to start new web app in Spyder IDE using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, rest, anaconda, spyder

This may be a noob question for some of you to answer, but I'm fairly new to the Anaconda software. I recently downloaded the django REST framework (version 3.1.3) I'm trying to develop a web app with the framework in Spyder IDE but I'm not exactly sure how to start it. I read the framework documentation at *http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/* but it's kind of vague. I want to know how exactly I can start the new app "**quickstart**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework is, in a way, a wrapper over Django that makes building REST services in Django easy.

Regardless of your IDE, it seems like you haven't got a hang of `Django` per se.

To start an app `quickstart`,

1. Install Python and pip
2. Install Django using pip: `pip install django` should do the trick.
3. Setup a database
4. Setup your first django app `django-admin.py startproject quickstart`

This would install Django and a Django app called quickstart. Your best place to start learning Django would be this excellent tutorial: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/

Also, please look at the Django docs, which are very exhaustive: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/

Please note, that both the above links are for Django 1.7.

However, if you do know about Django, then you just need to `pip install djangorestframework`, add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and get started.

Comment: Solved the problem. It turns out that I was using the right commands in the wrong window. I was supposed to write the commands in the command prompt within Spyder, not the Python console. Btw thanks for the tangowithdjango link, there's some really valuable information there!

Answer (score 5):

Django framework above 3+ version project in Spyder IDE

Follow this steps:

1. Install python
2. Execute this command `python -m pip install Django`
3. Use this command to confirm Django installed `python -m django --version`
4. Create new project, execute `django-admin startproject mysite`
5. Go to **Spyder IdE**, Open `Projects -> New Project`
6. Select `existing directory` in pop-up screen, `browse` the mysite folder.

Now you can see the Django created and imported in Spyder IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the command *django-admin startproject mysite* can be directly run in the Anaconda command terminal.

Alternatively you  can run the command in the command prompt of your computer, but you will have to run it in the directory "*C:\Users...\anaconda3\Scripts*"

The new django project will also get created in the Scripts folder

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+F6 then check 'command line options' after that type 'runserver' in the box. you must have selected manage.py when pressing run.